# Mark Element in List

Tags: python-3.x, list, boolean

I have an excercise  about prime numbers that requires me to write a function which takes a list of elements and a number p  and marks elements False which are in the range  2p, 3p...N

First I create a list of True and False:

```
true_value = [False, False] + [True for x in range(n-1)] #Let assumme that n=16
```

And then I write the function that find the even number in this list (with p = 2)

```
def mark_false(bool_list, p):
    range_new = [x for x in range(len(bool_list))]

    for i in range(2, len(range_new)):
        for j in range(p, len(range_new), p):
            if (i*p == range_new[j]) & (i*p <= len(range_new)):
                bool_list[j] = False
    return bool_list
```

This function help me to find the location of the even number (>2) and return to False

Example: `a = list_true(16)`

```
a = [False,False,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]

b = mark_false(a, 2)

b = [False,False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True]
```

This function `mark_false` does work but the problem is everytime I run it I have to  create a list `range_new` which takes a lot of time to calculate. So how do I rewrite this function so it can run faster without creating new lists?

Comment: One way you use this list is to get its length, but its length is just the length of your input. The other way is to do `range_new[j]`, but that's just `j`. Why do you even have a list?

Comment: Why is b[2] True?

Comment: Ah thank you,  change that code into j. However the speed is not increase much (Before: 580ms - After: 473ms)

Comment: Scott Hunter, oh because I want to find the even numbers which are greater than 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be doing things the long way around, searching for the `j` value that matches the multiple of `p` you want to set to `False`. But since you already know that value already, there's no need to search for it, just set it directly.

I'd do:

```
def mark_false(bool_list, p):
    for i in range(p, len(bool_list), p):   # p, 2*p, 3*p, ...
        bool_list[i] = False                # do the assignment unconditionally
```

You probably shouldn't need a `return` statement, since you're modifying the list you are passed in-place. Returning the list could make the API misleading, as it might suggest that the returned list is a new one (e.g. a modified copy).

If you *did* want to return a new list, you could create one with a list comprehension, rather than modifying the existing list:

```
def mark_false_copy(bool_list, p):
    return [x if i % p else False for i, x in enumerate(bool_list)]
```